# Windows Mobile 6.5 - CreateProcess runs exe differently than directly executing?

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5

I'm trying to launch `capture.exe` that takes a picture with my mobile device's camera when the user presses a button. When running `capture.exe` from the file explorer, it works as intended, leaving `capture.log` and `default.jpg` in the folder it was run from. When launching the exe through my app, however, the exe doesn't create `default.jpg` and `capture.log` contains:

```
pPropertyBag->Load( &PropBag, NULL) failed, hr = 80070037
```

The code I'm using to launch the exe is:

```
CreateProcess(L"\\MyPath\\capture.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

I have also tried passing the path as the 1st command line parameter, as well as an empty string, but for whatever reason `capture.exe` fails to run correctly when called programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt that Explorer is using CreateProcess, it's probably using [ShellExecuteEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa923541.aspx), which can sometimes give different behaviors.  It's definitely worth trying, as it's the only difference I can think of offhand.